# How is the output of the C program below 556? Please explain char *b=(char *)&a;

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a = 300;
    char *b = (char *)&a;
    b++;
    *b = 2;
    printf("%d", a);
    return 0;
}
```

- C Programming Problem
- Internal Memory Working

Comment: The results of the above code will be system dependent, depending on the size of an int relative to the size of a char,and possibly whether the system is big-endian or little-endian.

Comment: I am using GNU-GCC 32 bit Compiler. And CodeBlocks IDE.

Comment: @NarendraChoudhary I explain why in my answer

Comment: What output did you expect?

Comment: I was Expecting 2.

Comment: Can you explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in

```
char *b=(char *)&a;
```

you get the address of *a* as a pointer to a char

```
b++;*b=2;
```

set the next char to 2, that char is inside *a*, and the effect depends on the order of the bytes in your *int*, and also the size of an *int* of course

```
printf("%d",a);
```

For me the result is also 556, because the initial value 300 is 0x012C so the bytes 0x2C 0x01 0x00 0x00 in memory if *int* on 32b, when changing the second byte to 2 the value change to be 0x2C 0x02 0x00 0x00 so 0x22c so 556.

In case the bytes are in the reverse order the initial value 300 is the bytes 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x2C in memory (still in 32b), when changing the second byte to 2 the value change to be 0x00 0x02 0x01 0x2C so 0x2012c so 131372

Comment: How the Address can be in char?

Comment: @NarendraChoudhary: the `int` has 32 bits, hence 4 consecutive bytes. `char *b` is a point to `char`, which can be used to address these bytes.

Comment: Still confused in the statement "*b=(char *)&a;". Here "b" is a pointer variable of char type it should assign address of char type variable but through type casting i.e (char *) what we have done here. How the address changed to char type?

Comment: @NarendraChoudhary this is just casting, the address is the same for both, but when dereferencing the management is not the same, access an int (32b) or a char, that is all